# Does $f_n$ uniformly converge to $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

$f_n :[0, 1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R} \qquad x \mapsto x^n - x^{n+1}$

The sequence converges pointwise to the zero function. It converges uniformly if

$$\sup_{x \in [0, 1]} \; \big| \, f_{n}(x) - f(x) \, \big|$$

tends to zero. But I am not sure if it does or how to prove.

Comment: What sequence? I don't understand your recurrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $f_n'(x)=nx^{n-1}-(n+1)x^n=x^{n-1}\bigl(n-(n+1)x\bigr)$. Therefore, the maximum of $f_n$ is $f_n\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)$. But$$f_n\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)=\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^n\frac1{n+1}.$$Since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^n\frac1{n+1}=0,$$your sequence converges uniformly.

Comment: Nice, +1. For completeness I'll mention that the reason the limit is zero is that the first factor converges to $1/e$ and the second factor converges to zero.

Comment: @Bungo Actually, it is simpler to use the fact that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):0<\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^n\frac1{n+1}<\frac1{n+1}$$and the squeeze lemma.

Comment: Ah right, that is easier :-)

Answer (score 4):

The maximum of $x^n-x^{n+1}$ for $x\in [0,1]$ occurs when $x=\frac{n}{n+1}$ such that

$$x^n-x^{n+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\frac1{1+\frac1n}\right)^n\le \frac1{n+1}\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,n\to \infty$$

Comment: It's curious that you accepted a solution that is effectively the same as mine herein, but was posted after mine.  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $f_{n+1} = x f_n$ as $x\in[0,1]$ you have that $f_n$ is monotone. Use Dini's theorem [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem) to complete the proof.

Answer (score 2):

First note that we can write $x^n-x^{n+1}=x^n(1-x)$.

Given $0<\varepsilon<1$, if $1-\varepsilon<x\leq 1$ then
$$ x^n(1-x)\leq1-x<\varepsilon,$$
while if $0\leq x\leq 1-\varepsilon$ then
$$ x^n(1-x)<x^n<\varepsilon$$
for all sufficiently large $n$. Hence $f_n\to 0$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.